# Double '+' signs messing with !NaN in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, polish-notation, prefix-notation

Working a evaluator for Polish Notation and I was adding a way to distinguish if the string I got was a number or not using the isNaN function. This works fine, until you add + + to the string.

```js
function cuttingString(list) {
    let adjustArr = list.split(' ')
    let topper = []
    for (let i = 0; i < adjustArr.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(adjustArr[i])) {
            topper.push(adjustArr[i])
            console.log(topper)
        } else {
            let j = topper.pop()
            let k = topper.pop()

            if (adjustArr[i] === '+') {
                topper.push(parseInt(j) + parseInt(k))
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(cuttingString('* 1 2 30 +'))
```

works as expected with `'* 1 2 30 +'` it outputs `[1,2,30]` However, when I start moving around the operators, is when I get a NaN in the beginning of my arrays `[NaN, 1,2,30]` which is incredibly frustrating. Any ideas on how to fix this problem or other work arounds?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your problem. The code you've shown isn't enough - `adjustArr` seems like an array, however you claim to be passing a string. We have no idea how that string gets converted into the array.

Comment: @vlaz added sir!

Comment: You are missing a `return topper` for the code to actually work as example.

But I'm not sure I understand your problem, can you give an input string that shows it, and what you expected instead? You will get `NaN` if you are underflowing your buffer, so for example just the string `+` will result in `NaN` because it tries to pop two numbers and add them, but there are no numbers in `topper` yet. I noticed you have `*` in your example, yet you don't implement the `*` operator so far...

Comment: You have provided code that gives the desired output. You write *"when I start moving around the operators"*... but don't leave it to us to *guess* in which scenario it goes wrong. Please provide the code where it outputs NaN. Be aware that the first occurrence of a binary operator (like `+`) cannot occur before you have had two numbers, otherwise the binary operator has not enough arguments, and you would get a NaN (because one of the `pop` calls then returns `undefined`). So in that respect it makes no sense that the input starts with `*`. NB: I turned your code into a runnable snippet.

Comment: @trincot in Polish notation, the binary operator comes before its operands. You're thinking of _reverse_ Polish notation.

Comment: Yes I am, but that is exactly what the OP is doing in their code, so I think they have implemented the reverse and wrongly labelled it Polish instead of reverse Polish.

Comment: Apologies, I did not realize that was how you'd interpreted the question. Given the input string they're working with as an example, and the fact they're calling it Polish notation, I had just believed they had accidentally implemented reverse Polish notation when they're trying to implement normal Polish.

Comment: `* 1 2 30 +` is neither [tag:prefix-notation] nor [tag:postfix-notation]. It is some bizarre mixture of both. Please clarify your question and tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to implement reverse Polish notation, and so you cannot expect it to work correctly if you don't provide arguments *before* any of the binary operators. So you cannot randomly move the `+` around in the expression. A binary operator can only occur if there are at least two numbers available on the stack. If not, the call to `pop` will return `undefined` and `parseInt(undefined)` is `NaN`. Although you did not implement multiplication yet, it is problematic that the `*` occurs at a time when the stack is still empty.

It would make sense to have your function *return* the result, as your `console.log` will currently only output `undefined` and so you don't actually see the result of the calculation.

If indeed, your idea was to implement an evaluator for *reverse* Polish notation, then here is what I would adapt to your code:

```js
function cuttingString(list) {
    // Allow multiple spaces, also at start/end:
    let adjustArr = list.match(/\S+/g); 
    let topper = [];
    // Use for..of loop
    for (let token of adjustArr) {
        if (!isNaN(token)) {
            // Why not convert to number here...
            //   and allow decimals. Use unary plus
            topper.push(+token);
        } else if (topper.length < 2) {
            // Show error message when not enough arguments
            throw "not enough arguments for " + token;
        } else {
            let j = topper.pop();
            let k = topper.pop();
            if (token === '+') {
                topper.push(j + k);
            }
        }
    }
    // Verify that the evaluation is complete
    if (topper.length !== 1) {
        throw "Evaluation did not yield one value but " + topper.length;
    }
    // Return the value 
    return topper.pop();
}

console.log(cuttingString('1 2 30 + +')); // 33
console.log(cuttingString('1 2 + 30 +')); // 33
```

The two examples in this code are the only places where you can move the `+` operator to. For instance, neither of the following is valid:

```
console.log(cuttingString('1 2 + + 30'));
console.log(cuttingString('1 + 2 30 +'));
```

In either case, there arises a situation where the stack does not have enough arguments for a binary operator. The code above will provide a specific error message for that.